# Loudev multiselect with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to implement loudev multiselect with angular ng-options. Problem is that, it returns no error but the select list is empty.

```
 <select ng-options="item.label for item in list" 
         lp-multi-select multiple="multiple" 
         class="multi-select" ng-model="$scope.selected"></select>
```

Comment: "lp-multi-select" is this any custom directive?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, yes that is a custom directive. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not write "$scope" in the ng-model because it is not defined there.So the rule is "$scope.selected" in angular controller js is same as "selected" in ng-model like--

> ng-model="selected"

if you do so then it will return your multiple selected option as array of object.you can see example below(select two option then click the check button to see result)--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
  <select ng-options="item.label for item in list" multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" ng-model="selected">
  </select>
  <button ng-click="checkM()">Check</button>
        

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list=[{id:1,label:"banana"},{id:2,label:"mango"},{id:3,label:"apple"},{id:4,label:"water melon"}];
   $scope.checkM=function (){
    console.log($scope.selected);
   };
        });
  
    </script>

    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I'm so sorry for my late reply. Thanks for pointing that out, but I found out that the problem is that the loudev multiselect has its own way of printing out the option elements. That's why it does not work with Angular ng-options.